# Java - Splitting ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello all I am trying to scan the bottom 6 lines of a text file and display them in a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` currently it is being displayed as `[line7, line6, line5, line4, line3, line2]` I would prefer it to be displayed as a vertical list instead of the comma seperator.

```
ArrayList<String> bandWidth = new ArrayList<String>();
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("src/list.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String tmp;
try {
    while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        bandWidth.add(tmp);
        if (bandWidth.size() == 7)
            bandWidth.remove(0);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {   
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ArrayList<String> reversedSix = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = bandWidth.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    reversedSix.add(bandWidth.get(i));
                                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,bandWidth,null,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looping the `ArrayList` and produce a `String` with new line characters:

```
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < bandWidth.size(); i++)
{
    result += bandWidth.get(i) + "\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,result ,null,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Note: if this is outputting HTML, then use `<br \>` instead of `\n`.